# Program scroll bar arrow buttons functionality

Tags: wpf, silverlight

In some programs, for example, Microsoft Office Excel, when you’re at the end of the document being edited and then press a right or down arrow of the scrollbars, then, you scroll further and the edited area will grow, producing more space for entering data. Can this functionality be implemented in WPF?

I tried using ScrollBar instead of ScrollView to get more control, but didn’t succeed. If the scroll bar is at its maximum value, pressing the right or down (depending on the orientation) button of it doesn’t fire the scroll event.

Comment: This tutorial looks like a good start to learn how to control scrolling: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-implementing-iscrollinfo

Comment: Thank you, it looks like the solution, though requires a lot of coding.

Comment: Well i will said it depend a lot of what you have inside the scrollViewer, you can make the inside area grow in Height a percent based on the ScrollChangedEventArgs that you get when attach to the ScrollChange event. Or if you have a List you can just add a new item to the end of the list for example... when the scroll reach the end.